# how to remove selected option background color in IE browser through css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select

Here is the code what i tried to get rid from my problem,

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
select[optiopn:selected]{
background-color:white;
}
```

here is the screenshot [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it using like this.

```
select:focus::-ms-value {background-color: white; color:#000;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/afhx9du7/3/)

Comment: thank for u r reply,it is working in ie 10+ and it is not working in lower versions. @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: According to my knowledge, lower versions it is not possible to achieve this.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
background-color: transparent;
```